# Identifying cluster of exoplanets between Deneb and Vega

Tags: exoplanet

I noticed an interesting patern of exoplanets.

Is this a known phenomenon?[image: Cluster of exoplanets.]

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern?"

Answer (score 6):

That's the field the [Kepler telescope](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/main/index.html) was observing during its primary mission (before the [second reaction wheel failure](https://archive.stsci.edu/k2/)). The shape is due to the detector array.

I.e. this is not a real pattern in the actual distribution of exoplanets, it's a consequence of how the observations were done.